# Why is my global State not updating across other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am trying to store a global state using context to allow me to use the same state across different components.

The issue I am having is that when I set the global  state in 1 component and try to access it in the other component to use the state. It appears to be null and I cannot figure out why?

The first component where I set the global state in will always be rendered before the component shown that seems to have an empty value for the global state.

GlobalStateProvider component:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";



    const defaultActivitiesState = [];
  const globalStateContext = React.createContext(defaultActivitiesState);
  const dispatchStateContext = React.createContext([]);

  export const useGlobalState = () => 
  [
    React.useContext(globalStateContext),
    React.useContext(dispatchStateContext)
  ];

const GlobalStateProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer((state, newValue) => (state, newValue),
  defaultActivitiesState
  );



  return (
    <globalStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <dispatchStateContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </dispatchStateContext.Provider>
    </globalStateContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default GlobalStateProvider;
```

Component I set the global state in:

```
import react from "react";
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Popup, Polyline } from "react-leaflet";
import axios from "axios";
import polyline from "@mapbox/polyline";
import MapComp from "./MapComp";
import { useGlobalState } from "./GlobalStateProvider";

function Map() {
  // ------- global state
  const [activities, setActivities] = useGlobalState(); // global state
  //const [activities, setActivities] = useState([]);
  //const [polylines, setPolylines] = useState(null); // as empty array value is still truthy
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [mapMode, setMapMode] = useState("light");
  const [mapStyle, setMapStyle] = useState(
    "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
  );
  const [showMarkers, setShowMarkers] = useState(true);


  useEffect(() => {
    setActivitieData();
    console.log("activities after useEffect", activities)
  }, []);

  const polylines = useMemo(() => {
    console.log("activities inside memo", activities)
    console.log("activities.len  =", activities.length);
    if (activities.length) {
        console.log("past len");
      const polylineArray = [];
      for (const item of activities) {
        const polylineData = item.map.summary_polyline;
        const activityName = item.name;
        const activityType = item.type;
        polylineArray.push({
          positions: polyline.decode(polylineData),
          name: activityName,
          activityType: activityType,
        });
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
      return polylineArray;
    }
    return null;
  }, [activities]);


  const toggleMarkers = () => {
    setShowMarkers((show) => !show);
  };

  const getActivityData = async () => {
    console.log("calling")
    const response = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:8800/api/"
    );

    return response.data;
  };

  const setActivitieData = async () => {
    const activityData = await getActivityData();
    setActivities(activityData);
    console.log("Global activities state = ", activities);
    
  };


  return !isLoading && polylines ? (
    <>
      <div className="select-container">
        <button className="toggle-markers" onClick={() => toggleMarkers()}>
          Toggle Markers
        </button>

      </div>
      <MapComp
        className={`${mapMode}`}
        activityData={{ polylines }}
        showMarkers={showMarkers}
      />
    </>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <p>Loading...</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

component that has an empty value for global state:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useGlobalState } from './GlobalStateProvider';




function ActivityList() {

    const [activities, setActivities] = useGlobalState();
    let displayValues;


        displayValues = 
      activities.map((activity) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>{activity.name}</p>
            <p>{activity.distance}m</p>
            
          </div>
        );
      })
    
    return (
        <>
        <p>Values</p>
        {displayValues}
        </>
    );
}

export default ActivityList;
```

App.js:

```
function App() {
  
  return (
    <GlobalStateProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar />
        <AllRoutes />
      </div>
    </GlobalStateProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You're calling your dispatch with no arguments `setActivitieData();`, and also trying to log the value directly after the call instead of on the next render cycle.

Comment: @pilchard what arguments should the dispatch take then? I am confused as to how this will make a difference

Comment: @pilchard setActivitieData is just a function isn't the setActivities the dispatch?

Comment: Ah yes, I see now, you posted so much code I hadn't scrolled down. You declared your `reducer` as `(state, newValue) => (state, newValue)` but are calling it as `setActivities(activityData)` so only passing `state` but returning `newValue` which will always be undefined.

Comment: @pilchard I just cant seem to get the context to update it seems so I can use the context globally as the state

Comment: @pilchard if I only have one piece of data should I redefine my reducer if so in what way?

Comment: If you only ever want to overwrite the state use `useState` instead of `useReducer`. `const [state, dispatch] = React.useState(defaultActivitiesState);`

Comment: @pilchard what would be the best way for me to refactor my dispatch then to use only useState because yes I want to overwrite the state

Comment: I added it to my last comment. Just doing that should make it work somewhat.

Comment: @pilchard with that being done, I believe I am still not updating my context which is used globally how would I go about doing that from what I have? That state being the globalStateContext now